# Stair Rails Wall Side

Tags: railing

I want to put stair rails on the wall on 2 flights of steps in house.

From some online searching people say to put rail on right side wall coming down the stairs. This is fine on one set of steps but on the other set if I put on right side wall the light switch at bottom of stairs would be mid rail height. Is it ok to just put the rail on the left wall? Or do I move the light switch further up the wall?

Comment: I would put the rail on the open side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people are right handed, but "most" of humans are versatile enough to use their other extremities.

But your conundrum is really going to satisfied *best* if you go middle ground and trying to satisfy most people who'd have an issue with "switching hands" I'd say.

So install the railing *consistently,* all on one side... ( Right or left, depends if your coming or going )

But rails on *both* sides throughout traversing stairs takes care of it all...Can you do that ?

Move the light switch either up or down. Probably down, because most people would "complain" that they had to "reach too high" to operate it...

Comment: Thanks, I think the comment "consistently" is important. So I just have to decide if I feel like moving the light switch up a few inches or just go ahead and install on left wall. Both sides won't really work.

Comment: Best wishes with your project